# equivalencia ingles/español de cuentas y permisos regedit

Tags: windows, cmd, registro-windows

para establecer los permisos (y ejecutar regini) sobre una clave de registro, se requiere establecerlos en un archivo (que regini lee y que contiene estos permisos en formato [X X])

En inglés, de acuerdo con [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/regini.html) estos permisos son (Nombres de grupo o usuarios):

```
 1  - Administrators Full Access
 2  - Administrators Read Access
 3  - Administrators Read and Write Access
 4  - Administrators Read, Write and Delete Access
 5  - Creator Full Access
 6  - Creator Read and Write Access
 7  - World Full Access
 8  - World Read Access
 9  - World Read and Write Access
 10 - World Read, Write and Delete Access
 11 - Power Users Full Access
 12 - Power Users Read and Write Access
 13 - Power Users Read, Write and Delete Access
 14 - System Operators Full Access
 15 - System Operators Read and Write Access
 16 - System Operators Read, Write and Delete Access
 17 - System Full Access
 18 - System Read and Write Access
 19 - System Read Access
 20 - Administrators Read, Write and Execute Access
 21 - Interactive User Full Access
 22 - Interactive User Read and Write Access
 23 - Interactive User Read, Write and Delete Access
```

Según Microsoft, apenas dan una breve descripción de algunos

```
Administrators: Full Control
Creator/Owner: Full Control
World (Everyone): Full Control
System: Full Control
```

Como podemos ver, existen una serie de permisos para las siguientes cuentas:

```
Administrators
Creator
World
Power Users
System Operators
System
Interactive User
```

Hay algunos adicionales que no se mencionan como:

```
TrustedInstaller
CREATOR OWNER
```

etc...

Pero en español, estas cuentas difieren un poco, asumo que por la traducción de un idioma a otro. Ejemplo:

```
RESTRINGIDO
SYSTEM
user (nombre del usuario)
Administradores
Todos
Usuarios autentificados
```

etc....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es establecer la equivalencia para cada uno de inglés a español. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

No creo que sean diferentes los usuarios/grupos definidos en idioma español y en inglés, algunos que ves con diferente descripción, pueden ser usuarios o grupos creados para la administración en tu pc.

Tu puedes crear un usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y configurarlo como miembro o de uno o varios grupos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o crear un grupo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asignarle miembros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es por esta razón que probablemente veas grupos o usuarios diferentes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Los usuarios/cuentas creadas por el sistema operativo por default deben ser iguales.

Mas información:

- [Cómo administrar los permisos a usuarios y grupos en Windows 7](http://www.welivesecurity.com/la-es/2015/05/22/como-administrar-permisos-usuarios-grupos-usuarios-windows-7/)
- [Usuarios y grupos](http://www.ite.educacion.es/formacion/materiales/85/cd/windows/10Usuarios/index.html)

Comment: obviamente son los mismos en ingles y español y en chino y en cualquier idioma. Lo que sucede es que hay diferencias que pueden confundir debido al cambio de idioma y esas son las diferencias que quisiera establecer (una tabla de equivalencias en idiomas)

Comment: por ejemplo ¿cuál es el equivalente de "Usuarios autentificados" en la lista de arriba en inglés publicada en la pregunta?... O ¿cuál es el equivalente en español de "Interactive User", "Power Operators" y "System Operators" (a diferencia de system)?